# Create a tuple from a string and a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I need to combine a string along with a list of strings into a tuple so I can use it as a dictionary key.  This is going to be in an inner loop so speed is important.

The list will be small (usually 1, but occasionally 2 or 3 items).

What is the fastest way to do this?

Before:

```
my_string == "foo"
my_list == ["bar", "baz", "qux", "etc"]
```

After:

```
my_tuple == ("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "etc")
```

(Note: `my_list` must not be altered itself).

Comment: are you using _elements of_ or the entire tuple as dic key?

Comment: and if the list is small, why speed is so important?

Comment: The list used to create the key will be small.   The dictionary itself will be quite large.

Comment: And to answer your first question, the entire tuple will be the dictionary key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't speak for performance, but this is definitely the simplest I can think of:

```
my_tuple = tuple([my_string] + my_list)
```

Comment: `my_tuple = (my_string,) + tuple(my_list)` is some faster(about %15).

Comment: @ilius: Neat. I get why though since you only make tuples in the process, skipping the list bit.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is simply `my_tuple = tuple( my_list + [my_string] )`. I would certainly start with that and see if the performance is acceptable before trying to figure out any crazy ways of subverting the normal system for speed.

Comment: As the question, `my_string` must be the first element of `my_tuple` not the last.

Comment: Aha, then just reverse them as with BoltClock's solution.

Answer (score -3):

i think this way is better:

```
my_list = my_list.insert(0,my_string)
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
```

Comment: This modifies `my_list`, which OP doesn't want. And `list.insert()` doesn't return the list so you can't just pass it to the `tuple()` cast.

Comment: OP says `my_list` should not be altered.