# Looping through to create a tuple

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to implement the mass mail send out.

Here is the mass mail doc: [Just a link to the Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/#send-mass-mail)

In order to achieve this I need create this tuple:

```
datatuple = (
    ('Subject', 'Message.', 'from@example.com', ['john@example.com']),
    ('Subject', 'Message.', 'from@example.com', ['jane@example.com']),
)
```

I query the ORM for some recipients details. Then I would imagine there's some looping involved, each time adding another recipient to the tuple. All elements of the message are the same except for username and email.

So far I have:

```
recipients = notification.objects.all().values_list('username','email')
# this returns [(u'John', u'john@example.com'), (u'Jane', u'jane@example.com')]
for recipient in recipients:    
     to = recipient[1]               #access the email
     subject = "my big tuple loop"
     dear = recipient[0]              #access the name  
     message = "This concerns tuples!"
     #### add each recipient to datatuple
     send_mass_mail(datatuple)
```

I've been trying something along the lines of this : 
[SO- tuple from a string and a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453979/create-a-tuple-from-a-string-and-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: What trouble are you facing?

Comment: you can't add anything to tuples because tuples are immutable.  Use a list instead.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky that isn't true. It would not result in the same object being altered, but tuples support increments just as well as integers and strings.

Comment: @Ryan do you mean `datatuple += (subject, message, 'from@example.com', [to, ])`

Comment: @Ryan BTW, maybe the line `send_mass_mail(datatuple)` should be unindented and taken out of the loop

Comment: @Pynchia: from Python docs: "[Tuples are immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)".  They don't "support increments", they support concatenation.  But every time you concatenate tuples, you get a new instance, which means you keep allocating memory on every concatenation.  If you need to extend a tuple, why not just use a list?

Comment: @Beransky yes I meant concatenation, the `+=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is pretty simple with a comprehension.

```
emails = [
    (u'Subject', u'Message.', u'from@example.com', [address])
    for name, address in recipients
]
send_mass_mail(emails)
```

Note that we leverage Python's ability to unpack `tuple`s into a set of named variables. For each element of `recipients`, we assign its zeroth element to `name` and its first element to `address`. So in the first iteration, `name` is `u'John'` and `address` is `u'john@example.com'`.

If you need to vary the `'Message.'` based on the name, you can use string formatting or any other formatting/templating mechanism of your choice to generate the message:

```
emails = [
    (u'Subject', u'Dear {}, Message.'.format(name), u'from@example.com', [address])
    for name, address in recipients
]
```

Since the above are list comprehensions, they result in `emails` being a `list`. If you *really* need this to be a `tuple` instead of a `list`, that's easy, too:

```
emails = tuple(
    (u'Subject', u'Message.', u'from@example.com', [address])
    for name, address in recipients
)
```

For this one, we're actually passing a generator object into the `tuple` constructor. This has the performance benefits of using a generator without the overhead of creating an intermediate `list`. You can do that pretty much anywhere in Python where an iterable argument is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bit of cleanup needed here:

1) actually build the tuple in the loop (this is a bit tricky since you need the extra comma to ensure that a tuple is appended and not the values from the tuple)

2) move the send_mass_mail call outside the loop

This should be working code:

```
recipients = notification.objects.all().values_list('username','email')
# this returns [(u'John', u'john@example.com'), (u'Jane', u'jane@example.com')]
datatuple = []
for recipient in recipients:    
    to = recipient[1]               #access the email
    subject = "my big tuple loop"
    dear = recipient[0]              #access the name  
    message = "This concerns tuples!"
    #### add each recipient to datatuple
    datatuple.append((subject, message, "from@example.com", [to,]),)
send_mass_mail(tuple(datatuple))
```

EDIT:
jpmc26's technique is definitely more efficient, and if you're planning to have a large email list to send to you should use that. Most likely you should use whichever code makes the most sense to you personally so that when your requirements change you can easily understand how to update.